# Horizontal line in vim

Tags: linux, vim

What does a horizontal line in vim mean? While editing a remote file I see a horizontal line in the current line.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8GXB.png]

I don't see it while editing local files

**Edit:**
cursorline is not shown until I save the file(:w). When I type :w and enter password, cursorline appears. Why does it have such a behavior? When I edit file in remote machine cursorline is turned off and is not shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "editing a remote file"? Starting vim on a different machine in an SSH session? Because obviously the other machine probably has a different configuration from yours.

Comment: @NiklasB. I mean running this command on my own machine: "vim scp://example.com//path/to/script"

Comment: So it's a difference whether you use `vim /local/file` or `vim scp://remote/file`? Or are you comparing gvim with vim? That's weird.

Comment: What version of Netrw are you using? `:echo g:loaded_netrwPlugin` Different versions may need different workarounds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have answered, the effect is probably being caused by the [`cursorline` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cursorline%27).

You can track down what is script made the most recent change to an option by running the command `set optname?` under the [`verbose` command](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Averbose):

```
:verbose set cursorline?
```

You will probably just find that the Netrw plugin set it; Netrw handles local directory browsing and remote directory/file access like your `scp://` example. Netrw adjusts `cursorline` (and `cursorcolumn`) for its own purposes (e.g. directory listings), but it tries to restore the value to the “user value”. Unfortunately, its idea of the “user value” is captured when part of the Netrw code loads and is not updated afterwards.

My guess is that, somehow (via some other plugin, or bit of configuration), `cursorline` is set when Netrw loads (and captures its value), but it is later reset by the time you start editing the first file. Then, when you later save the file (`:w`), Netrw restores the “captured” value. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any good way to update this “captured” value of  the `cursorline` option (there is no “external” access to the script variable it uses, and it does not “recapture” if you manually reload the file).

What you can do, however, is explicitly load the bit of Netrw that “captures” `cursorline` when your desired value is active. You could do that with the following two commands early in your `~/.vimrc` (possibly at the very top, if necessary—it needs to be before the first time `autoload/netrw.vim` would ever be used):

```
set nocursorline
runtime autoload/netrw.vim " will 'capture' cursorline and cursorcolumn values
```

Netrw will still set/reset `cursorline` (and `cursorcolumn`), but as long as the value you normally want matches the value that is active right before Netrw is loaded, then you will not notice it.

Comment: it "looks" at least that the captured, well, really hard-coded, value is in `g:netrw_cursorline`: http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim?name=vim73#161 , but in the most current version, that variable is deprecated and replaced with `netrw_usercul`.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: The “capture” variables I described are `s:netrw_usercul` and `s:netrw_usercuc`. Their values are taken from the values of the `cursorline` and `cursorcolumn` options when `autoload/netrw.vim` is loaded (i.e. not hard-coded). Netrw v140 (shipped with stock Vim 7.3) has a bug in that these session variables are never created if `g:netrw_cursorline` is pre-defined (i.e. in your `~/.vimrc`)—subsequent uses of Netrw functionality will generate “undefined variable” errors (though these errors may “scroll by” mostly harmlessly). The exact workaround depends on the version in use.

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite know the simplest solution to get get netrw to really capture the right value, but at very least (since for me, nocul is right,) adding:

```
let g:netrw_cursorline=0
```

To the end of my `~/.vimrc` seems to have fixed the problem for me.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I don't understand why I started having this problem all of a sudden and why this fixed it lol

Answer (score 4):

It's the [`cursorLine`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cursorline%27). Its appearance is defined in your colorscheme. The one on the remote machine is probably different than yours or there's a mismatch between your client/server's `$TERM`.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, "**:set cursorline**" or "**:set nocursorline**" to turn the line on or off.

The command "**vim scp://....**" copies the remote file onto your local machine (i.e. machine where the "vim" process runs), then opens the file in "vim" for you to edit, then, if you have modified the file, copies the file back onto the remote system.  As such, syntax highlighting etc. is determined ***only*** by "vim" on your local machine.

Files with the same syntax type ("**:se syn**" to show current syntax highlighting scheme) are highlighted the same way.  Do the files, in which you see the difference, have the same syntax type?

Comment: cursorline is not shown until I save the file(`:w`). When I type `:w` and enter password, _cursorline_ appears. Why does it have such a behavior? When I edit file in remote machine cursorline is turned off

Comment: Re. seeing the cursor line only after a `:w`: I'd have to guess that it's a terminal render bug, either in that particular combination of vim/shell/OS, or in the terminal program you use (putty, Mac OS "terminal", etc.).  Without doing a `:w`, what happens if you just do a `ctrl-l` to redraw the screen?  Do you see the cursor line then?

Comment: Re. "edit file in remote machine cursorline is turned off": what does that mean?  Did you SSH to the remote machine and log in, then issue `vi file` (as oppsoed to doing a `vim scp://..."` on your local machine)?  If so, your `cursorline` is determined by the file's syntax in vi _on that machine_.  To check the value of `cursorline` for that particular's syntax, do `:se cursorline?`.

Answer (score 2):

Version 142 of netrw.vim has fixed this bug, at least for me (vim 7.3, old netrw.vim version was 140, running under cygwin).

You can get the latest version here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075